# Populate XML elements in existing document

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this string of XML elements in a document

```
<dmc><avee><modelic></modelic><sdc></sdc><chapnum></chapnum><section></section>
<subsect></subsect><subject></subject><discode></discode><discodev></discodev>
<incode></incode><incodev></incodev><itemloc></itemloc></avee></dmc>
```

What I need to do is now populate those elements with user inputted variables using Linq. I currently have:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sgmlReader);
doc.Element("modelic").Add(MI);
doc.Element("sdc").Add(sd);
doc.Element("chapnum").Add(sys);
doc.Element("section").Add(subsys);
doc.Element("subsect").Add(subsubsys);
doc.Element("subject").Add(unit);
doc.Element("discode").Add(dc);
doc.Element("discodev").Add(dcv);
doc.Element("incode").Add(infcode);
doc.Element("incodev").Add(infCV);
doc.Element("itemloc").Add(loc);
```

(yes I'm using sgmlReader but this works fine in my program in other areas) I'm clearly missing something fundamental as it's giving me a `NullReferenceException was unhandled - Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Any ideas/suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Element()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method only matches the immediate children of the container.

You can either chain [Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) into [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx):

```
doc.Descendants("modelic").First().Add(MI);
```

Or navigate to the immediate parents of the elements you want to modify:

```
doc.Root.Element("avee").Element("modelic").Add(MI);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        var avee = dmc.Root.Element("avee");
        avee.Element("modelic").Value = MI;
        avee.Element("sdc").Value = sd;
```

Just repeat the last line for each of your remaining elements (`chapnum`, `section`...).

The problem was that first you have to retrieve root element (`dmc`), then `avee`, and then you can set values for child elements of `avee`.